# Azure Virtual Machine Android Studio Install Error

Tags: android, azure, android-studio, virtual-machine, remote-server

I am not sure what is the reason here, the user I am logged in belongs to the `Administrators` group but when I am trying to install `Android Studio` it gives the following error. I have tried running the installer as administrator, any pointers are appreciated.

[image]

Comment: It looks like you are running the command from the PowerShell window. Is powershell running under elevated priviliges?

Comment: no the powershell is just in the background i am running the standard studio installer

Comment: @harshitpthk then run the installer using `Run as Administrator` mode